# Lombok's @Value not working with additional constructor

Tags: java, lombok

I am using Lombok's @Value annotation like this:

```java
@Value
public class Foo {
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

As per the official documentation, this should be equivalent to `@Getter @FieldDefaults(makeFinal=true, level=AccessLevel.PRIVATE) @AllArgsConstructor @ToString @EqualsAndHashCode`. So far everything looks good, I can check the code with a little test and see that the `@AllArgsConstrucotr` is present.

However, I need to add an additional constructor that calls the All-Args Constructor and this breaks everything:

```java
@Value
public class Foo {
    int x; // IDE warning: Variable 'x' might not have been initialized
    int y; // IDE warning: Variable 'y' might not have been initialized
    
    public Foo(Bar bar) {
        this(bar.getA(), bar.getB()); // IDE warning: Expected 1 arguments but found 2
    }
}
```

If I'm trying to run a simple test, I'll get a compilation error:

```
  required: ...Bar
  found:    int,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

In short, the @AllArgsConstructor is no longer generated, and I need manually add it back in order to enforce lombok  to generate it:

```java
@Value
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Foo {
    //...
}
```

Is there a better way of doing it? Can I enforce this through some configuration? Is this a known issue in Lombok? The version I am using in this project is `1.18.18`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your quote from the lombok documentation is incomplete. The actual [lombok documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value) is very clear about this behaviour:

> In practice, @Value is shorthand for: final @ToString @EqualsAndHashCode @AllArgsConstructor @FieldDefaults(makeFinal = true, level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE) @Getter, except that explicitly including an implementation of any of the relevant methods simply means that part won't be generated and no warning will be emitted.
>
> [...]
>
> Also, *any* explicit constructor, no matter the arguments list, implies lombok will not generate a constructor.

And the next sentence contains the solution:

> If you do want lombok to generate the all-args constructor, add `@AllArgsConstructor` to the class.

If you need the additional constructor, you must add the `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation.

Comment: oh, I missed it. thanks!